# MVC2 / nHibernate / nUnit Test Failed on Build Server

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, nunit, 64-bit, cvs

I have a C# 4.0 MVC 2 application using nUnit 2.5, nHibernate 2.1.

I have a TestFixture that passes when ran locally (Windows 7 (64bit)), but fails when is compiled on the build server (Windows Server 2003 (64bit))

The code that the test fails on is defined in the [SetUp]:

```
_session = NHibernateSession.GetDefaultSessionFactory().OpenSession();
new SchemaExport(configuration).Execute(false, true, false, _session.Connection, null);
```

The error I get is:

```
Database was not configured through Database method. ----> Hibernate.HibernateException : Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to install SQLite on the server which is running the unit test. Or at least add the dll to the gac.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I didn't wan't to go down this path to allow a simple deployment to other servers.  Do you know of a way to package the SQLite dll as part of the deployment to the build server?

Comment: You can try to copy it in the bin directory. Add the dll to source control and make a reference. I'm not sure if it will work.